# How can I check to see whether an indexPath is valid or not in UITableView in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I just want to make sure that the UITableView doesn't crash if there is an invalid indexPath.

Comment: Don't use inappropriate API.

Comment: where did you get the _index-path_ from? _index-paths_ should be generated based on your model...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by checking both section and row of indexPath is valid.

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = YOUR_INDEX_PATH;

// If |isValid| is true, |indexPath| is valid, if not, |indexPath| is invalid
BOOL isValid = [TABLE_VIEW numberOfSections] > indexPath.section &&
               [TABLE_VIEW numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] > indexPath.row;

if (isValid) {
  NSLog(@"Valid"); // Do whatever you want if |indexPath| is valid
} else {
  NSLog(@"Not valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a test to your view controller.

```
- (BOOL)isValidIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return (indexPath.section < self.tableView.numberOfSections &&
            indexPath.row < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]);
}
```

Then when you need to check the index path:

```
if ([self isValidIndexPath:indexPath]) {
    ...
}
```

It would be even better as a category, so all table views and controllers could use it.

```
@interface UITableView (IndexPathTest)
- (BOOL)isValidIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation UITableView (IndexPathTest)

- (BOOL)isValidIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return (indexPath.section < self.numberOfSections &&
            indexPath.row < [self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]);
}

@end
```

Then for any table view controller:

```
if ([self.tableView isValidIndexPath:indexPath]) {
    ...
}
```